# Play Store closed BETA versioning wrt production versioning

Tags: android, google-play, beta

I'm setting up a closed BETA on play store, but I don't intend for this BETA to ever be promoted to production. Therefore, and wanted to know how the versioning interacted with the production track, specifically:

1) I have a current prod version of 1002. I am uploading closed beta as version 1003. Now, if I go ahead and upload a version 1004 on the production track, what will my closed BETA group users see - 1003 or 1004?

2) If the answer to the above is 1004, then how do I get around it (ie. how do I continue serving the same BETA build to my closed group? Can I for example upload it as 1099 on the closed BETA track, and then continue with normal increments on the production track (1002, 1003, 1004...)?

I'd appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

yes so having 1003 In closed track, and 1004 is uploaded on prod, beta testers will get 1004 as well...

And no 2 is not an option , 1099 in closed means, next upload to be 1100 ( be it alpha,beta, prod)